# Can I import submodules outside of the "main": "index.js" file from a local yarn workspace dependency package?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have the following monorepo structure (using yarn workspaces).

```
packages
  common
    src
      index.js
      module1.js
      module2.js
    package.json
  user
    src
      index.js
      moduleA.js
      mobuleB.js
    package.json
package.json
```

My root `package.json`

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": ["packages/*"]
}
```

`package.json` from `common`

```
{
  "name": "@packages/common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

`package.json` from `user`

```
{
  "name": "@packages/user",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@packages/common": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

As expected, the `user` package needs to "use / import" from the `common` package.

Here is my question: if I want to import `module1` or `module2` from the `common` package. Is there a way to do it directly, like:

```
import { Foo } from "@packages/common/src/module1";
```

Is this an anti-pattern? Should I only `import` from `@packages/common`, which would imply importing from `common/src/index.js` (given the `main` property on `package.json)`?

I pretty much would like to have access to any `src/sub-folder/sub-file` from the `common` package. Should I `import | re-export` everything from the `common/src/index.js` file, or is there a way to get those other files directly?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. The following should work just fine:

```
import { Foo } from "@packages/common/src/module1";
```

---

**OBS:** The following details are specific for Next.js projects, but the idea might be the same for other projects.

Just keep in mind that if you need those files (the ones that live outside of your next project folder) to be transpiled, you're gonna need to use the `next-transpile-modules` package.

More details can be found here:

- [Medium: Sharing code between NextJS applications](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/sharing-code-between-nextjs-applications-2c0f3b415e1)
- [nextjs-sharing-code-monorepo](https://github.com/cpv123/nextjs-sharing-code-monorepo)
- [next-transpile-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules)

Comment: Is there any way to omit the `src` dir, i.e., `import { Foo } from "@packages/common/module1"`?

Comment: Anyone know how we can do this outside of NextJs?  Question didn't specify NextJs